# Anyone know the name of this Russian puzzle game?

Tags: game-identification

I found a picture of a game from my childhood:

[image: Screenshot of the game]

And now I am wondering what game is this? All I remember is that it was a Russian puzzle game.

Comment: I clicked on this question expecting to see a screenshot of Tetris, honestly.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

According to some reverse image search, I found some sites in Russian.

The Russian title is **Остров Драконов - Башня Знаний 2**, which google translates to:

**Dragon Island. The Tower of Knowledge 2**

Here's the Russian cover:

[image]

I found a [site](http://legendsworld.net/adventure/game/11346) that has some more info about this game:

> A long time ago in a dreamland on the shore of the blue sea settled an evil witch. She wanted to conquer the people of this country and lord over them as their mistress. But how to achieve this, she did not know. Helping her was ancient book, which tells about dragons, burning everything in their paths. The sorceress had sent her brothers a giant cub to turn the dragon into a weapon of intimidation. And then ... you need to save the little dragon from prison and return it to its parents - wise dragons living on the island.

Answer (score 18):

The game you're looking for is called *Dragon Island. The Tower of Knowledge 2*. The original Cyrillic title is *ОСТРОВ ДРАКОНОВ. БАШНЯ ЗНАНИЙ 2*.

It can be found on several places [**around the web**](https://www.google.de/webhp?hl=de&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAGoVChMI1Zf5vuH2xwIVgtYUCh3pnA0Q&biw=1920&bih=979#hl=de&q=%D0%9E%D0%A1%D0%A2%D0%A0%D0%9E%D0%92%20%D0%94%D0%A0%D0%90%D0%9A%D0%9E%D0%9D%D0%9E%D0%92.%20%D0%91%D0%90%D0%A8%D0%9D%D0%AF%20%D0%97%D0%9D%D0%90%D0%9D%D0%98%D0%99%202).

I found the game via the Google Image Search.

Comment: Hey Nitro.de, please don't use backticks `\`` for emphasis, use **bold** (`**bold**`) or *italics* (`*italics*`) instead. Backticks are for code snippets or file paths. They are read out-loud letter-by-letter when using screen readers, because anything in backticks are not expected to be full, pronouncable words. You can read more on [this meta discussion](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7437/28182)

Comment: @Robotnik Again learned something new, thank you. Didn't know that screen readers read them this way.